# How can I create a closure that propagates parameters to a function with an unknown signature?

Tags: rust, closures

I'm trying to create a decorator for a function, but I don't know what parameters the function will have. This is the kind of structure I'm going for:

```rust
pub fn decorator<T, *args, F: Fn(*args) -> T>(function: F) -> F {
    move |*args| {
        println!("Hello World!");
        (function)(*args)
    }
}
```

I know the code above is not even close to correct, and doesn't conform to rust's syntax, but it should adequately explain what I'm trying to accomplish. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Within code as-is-written, it is not possible or at least extremely cumbersome. This is because any `F` that is callable with some parameters of types `A`, `B`, `C` is completely different from any other `F` with some other, fewer, or more parameters. What you need is a proc-macro, which will be able to inspect the signature and created the necessary glue-code.

Comment: Can you show how you'd like to use this decorator?